# How to remote trigger a Jenkins workflow?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I have troubles with triggering a workflow with both cli and rest api. It tried it in the same way as it works for normal jobs. For the rest api neither `build` nor `buildWithParameters` posts work.

Anyone any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The CLI command is not yet implemented: [JENKINS-28071](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28071)

The REST APIs `build` and `buildWithParameters` should work exactly the same as for freestyle projects.